# java.lang.UnixProcess inherently slow executing `find` on NTFS?

Tags: java, scala, find, ntfs

I was trying to get a list of files under a directory using:

```
val d = "..." // Path to a directory on a NTFS partition
val pb = new ProcessBuilder("find", d, "-type", "f", "-print")
pb.directory(new java.io.File(d))
val p = pb.start()
p.waitFor()
val listOfFiles = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(p.getInputStream).getLines
```

However, the `p.waitFor()` is taking more than a minute to finish.
If I execute `find . -type f -print` in *bash* while on the directory, however, it takes less than a second to finish.
Therefore, is `java.lang.UnixProcess` inherently slow on a NTFS partition, or am I doing something wrong?

Using Scala 2.8.1, Java 1.6.0_24-b07 on a Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consume the stdout and stderr streams of the process because `find` might be writing to them and blocking.

Take a look at the post, [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html), for more information. They use a StreamGobbler to read the output streams so your process doesn't hang.

Comment: Using the idea of the article, I moved the processing of the `InputStream` to a _Thread_ (actually, a _Callable_), and now it works. Thanks!